# How to combine this with variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Having a brain fart here. I have this code:

```
$(function() {

    $('#featured-top .option').click(function(){

        $('#featured-top .option a').html('Close');

        $('#featured-top .featured-content').slideToggle();

    });

});
```

This line here:

```
$('#featured-top .option a').html('Close');
```

Im trying to use this:

```
$(this).html('Close');
```

But how do I access the link using the selector? I tried:

```
$(this + 'a').html('Close');
```

But that doesnt work. Its simple, I know but for some reason I cant figure it out all of a sudden.

Comment: Maybe `$(this).find('a');` or `$(this).closest('a')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't do that way. You need to use:

```
$('#featured-top .option').click(function(){
  // Use this way:
  $(this).find('a').html('Close');
  // If you wanna change this as well, you can use:
  $(this).closest("#featured-top").find('.featured-content').slideToggle();
});
```